# MySQL get sum of columns from two tables having multiple records of same product

Tags: php, mysql

[image: produced Table]

[image: order_items table]

My requirement is to get sum of produced items quantity and sold items quantity.
My query is

```
select productions.created_at, 
       produced.expiry_date,
       items.id as item_id,
       items.quantity as 
       sold_quantity,
       items.product_price as sailing_price,
       sum(produced.quantity) as total_produced,
       sum(items.quantity) as total_sold 
from productions inner join produced_products as produced
on produced.production_id = productions.id 
inner join store_order_items as items 
on items.product_keeping_id = produced.keeping_id 
group by produced.keeping_id, items.product_keeping_id
```

This query returns

`[0] => Array
        (
            [created_at] => 2017-07-13 10:25:52
            [expiry_date] => 2017-07-31
            [item_id] => 2
            [sold_quantity] => 1.00
            [sailing_price] => 120
            [total_produced] => 6.000
            [total_sold] => 2.00
        )`

`[1] => Array
        (
            [created_at] => 2017-07-07 13:30:25
            [expiry_date] => 0000-00-00
            [item_id] => 3
            [sold_quantity] => 1.00
            [sailing_price] => 120
            [total_produced] => 16.000
            [total_sold] => 4.00
        )`

These records are wrong. It should return

```
 [0] (
        [total_sold] => 1
       ),
  [1] (
       [total_sold] => 1
      )
```

How can i get right result

Comment: are you calculating total sold value w.r.t to 2nd table only (item) or you need the sum value with combining with product table ?

Comment: I need separate sum of quantity from both tables as  total_produced and total_sold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
select productions.created_at, 
produced.expiry_date,
items.id as item_id,
items.quantity as sold_quantity,
items.product_price as sailing_price,
sum(produced.quantity) as total_produced,
(SELECT sum(t1.quantity) FROM `store_order_items` as t1 where t1.product_keeping_id = produced.keeping_id ) as total_sold
from productions inner join produced_products as produced
on produced.production_id = productions.id 
inner join store_order_items as items 
on items.product_keeping_id = produced.keeping_id 
group by produced.keeping_id, items.product_keeping_id
```